# How to manipulate and separate strings into two columns in a data.table

Tags: r, string, data.table

I have 17000 records and need to break up the variable YearSem as below in record1, into two separate columns 'Year' and 'Sem'.

```
student_ID=c("1001","1002","1005","1010")
YearSem=c("2011/1","2012/2","2015/1","2015/2")
Grade=c("Pass","Fail","Pass","Fail")
record1<-data.table(student_ID,YearSem,Grade)
```

What I need

```
student_ID=c("1001","1002","1005","1010")
Year=c("2011","2012","2015","2015")
Sem=c("1","2","1","2")
Grade=c("Pass","Fail","Pass","Fail")
record2<-data.table(student_ID,Year,Sem,Grade)
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto Consider to post the options as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already using *data.table*, you could use `tstrsplit()` to split the columns.  It is part of the latest data.table CRAN release, version 1.9.6.  We can split the `YearSem` column into two new columns, and then remove it all in one go.

```
setcolorder(
    record1[, c("Year", "Sem", "YearSem") := 
        c(tstrsplit(YearSem, "/", fixed = TRUE), list(NULL))],
    c(1, 3, 4, 2)
)
```

Which gives

```
   student_ID Year Sem Grade
1:       1001 2011   1  Pass
2:       1002 2012   2  Fail
3:       1005 2015   1  Pass
4:       1010 2015   2  Fail
```

You could add `type.convert = TRUE` to `tstrsplit()` if you want the new columns to be converted to their most appropriate types (here it would be integer).

Comment: I am trying to stick with data table generally because even though this data set is small I have a ridiculous amount of Learning Management System variables for each student so it is better for me.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
separate(record1, YearSem, into=c('Year', 'Sem'), convert=TRUE)
#     student_ID Year Sem Grade
#1:       1001 2011   1  Pass
#2:       1002 2012   2  Fail
#3:       1005 2015   1  Pass
#4:       1010 2015   2  Fail
```

---

Another option is `read.table` if we don't want to use any packages.  But, as it is a `data.table`

```
record1[,c('Year', 'Sem') := read.table(text=YearSem,sep='/')
         ][,YearSem:= NULL]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a way of not using any other package...

```
YearSem = matrix(unlist(strsplit(YearSem,'/')),2,length(YearSem))
Year = YearSem[1,]
Sem = YearSem[2,]

> Year
[1] "2011" "2012" "2015" "2015"
> Sem
[1] "1" "2" "1" "2"
```

Comment: Or more commonly, `do.call(rbind, strsplit(YearSem,'/'))` or (less commonly) `"colnames<-"(do.call(rbind, strsplit(YearSem,'/')), c("Year", "Sem"))`...

Answer (score 1):

How about using `str_split_fixed`?

```
 record1$year <- str_split_fixed(record1$YearSem, "/", 2)[,1]
 record1$sem <- str_split_fixed(record1$YearSem, "/", 2)[,2]
```